# Cannot link using libwebkitgtk-1.0.so because libgeoclue.so.0 is missing

Tags: c, compilation

I am having trouble with compiling the source code on my computer, it compiles just fine on my lab machine, but not on my personal machine.

My personal machine is Ubuntu 16.04, as well as the lab machine.

```
gcc wrapper.c wrapper.h browser.c -L /usr/lib/ -g -Wall `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0 webkit-1.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0 webkit-1.0` -o browser
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libgeoclue.so.0, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so: undefined reference to `geoclue_master_get_default'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so: undefined reference to `geoclue_accuracy_get_details'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so: undefined reference to `geoclue_master_create_client_async'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so: undefined reference to `geoclue_master_client_create_position_async'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so: undefined reference to `geoclue_master_client_set_requirements_async'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so: undefined reference to `geoclue_position_get_position_async'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'browser' failed
make: *** [browser] Error 1
```

I have tried installing all the geoclue packages that I could find in the repositories.

I have installed the libgeoclue-dev, libgeoclue0, libgeocode-glib-dev, libgeoclue-2-0, and libgeoclue-2-dev packages.

All the packages were installed via apt-get.

After running a find on libgeoclue* I found libgeoclue.so so I created a softlink to libgeoclue.so.0 and it still will not compile:

After adding echo to the front of gcc I get the following outout

```
gcc wrapper.c wrapper.h browser.c -L /usr/lib/ -g -Wall -pthread -I/usr/include/webkitgtk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libsoup-2.4 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/webkitgtk-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lwebkitgtk-1.0 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lsoup-2.4 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -ljavascriptcoregtk-1.0 -lglib-2.0 -o browser
```

I cannot figure out how to install libgeoclue.so.0 on my machine, any help?

If you need any other information feel free to let me know.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should not normally compile header files.

Comment: This is actually for a class, and they gave us the make file. I agree that it is weird.

Comment: How did you install the GeoClue packages?  `sudo apt-get install geoclue-dev` might be about right — the `-dev` might not be necessary.  Since you've not stated what you did, we can't help much more.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have edited the original post with the packages I have installed. I have install geoclue package.

Comment: Two steps: (1) `find / -name libgeoclue.so.0`; that tells you where the library is installed, if it is installed.  You might need to lose access errors: `find / -name libgeoclue.so.0 2>/dev/null`.  (2) Put `echo` in front of your GCC command line so you see what the `pkgconfig` commands are producing.  If the `find` can't find `libgeoclue.so.0`, then you need to find what you have got; refine the search to `find / -name 'libgeoclue*' 2>/dev/null` and expect to see more output.  If it can, then you need to review the actual command line to see why the right directory isn't listed to GCC.

Comment: Also, use the same two steps on your lab machine and compare the results.  Also, it could be a permissions issue, even though it isn't explicitly one.  Maybe a directory that should be accessible isn't.  That information might be in the errors sent to `/dev/null` — but it might be hard to spot.  You could also try using `apt-get` on the lab machine to list the installed packages, perhaps.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have tried the following suggestions and still have no luck. I have added the outputs to the original post. The commands on the lab machine were the same output as on my local machine.

Comment: That is unexpected. Try running the `file` command on both machines. Have you checked file sizes?  Checksums (e.g. `md5sum`)?  Is the version of GCC the same? Clutching at straws here.  You may end up needing to use the `-v` option to `gcc` on the machines to compare what's going on.  I assume that there isn't an issue with 32-bit vs 64-bit builds and/or libraries.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler By run the file command do you mean to run the file command on the libgeoclue libs?

Comment: Yes.  `file /usr/lib/libgeoclue.so.0` etc (the `file` command takes a list of file names and analyzes each in turn).  You said you found the same library names in the same places on the two machines, so there's something else that's different about them.  The file sizes, the file types, the file checksums may all be different.  Some of the differences may be legitimate; others may not.  But there is something weird going on if your detective work is accurate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Solved it by taking a gamble, the libgeoclue.so.0 was a softlink to libgeoclue.so.0.0.0, I didn;t have the .0.0.0 so I copied the .0.0.0 to my personal computer and created another softlink to it and it works. :)

Comment: It had to be something like that, but without the complete lists of files, it was hard to know.  You had to spot the significant difference and work around it.  Glad you're fixed now, but you might still want to check how your machine didn't get the right file in the right place.